# combining infiniteajaxscroll, masonry, imagesloaded and own script

Tags: jquery, ajax, masonry

Im working on a page and have some troubles to get some different jquery stuff (masonry with imagesloaded, some own stuff and iac (http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/) ) to work together and need some help:

so if I write it this way, everything works but not the iac:

```
(function ($) {
    var $container = $('.portfolio');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.portfoliobox'
        });
    });

    var ias = $.ias({
        container: ".portfolio",
        item: ".portfoliobox",
        pagination: ".pagination",
        next: ".older a",
        delay: 1200
    });

    ias.on('render', function (items) {
        $(items).css({opacity: 0});
    });
    ias.on('rendered', function (items) { 
        msnry.appended(items);
    });

    $("dt").click(function () { 
        $(this).toggleClass("close open");
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast", function () { 
            $('.portfolio').masonry();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

if i write it that way, the ias is working, but the click function is not working for the reloaded items (and the imageslaoded is missing..):

```
(function ($) {
    var container = document.querySelector('.portfolio');
    var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
        itemSelector: '.portfoliobox',
    });
    var ias = $.ias({
        container: ".portfolio",
        item: ".portfoliobox",
        pagination: ".pagination",
        next: ".older a",
        delay: 1200
    });
    ias.on('render', function (items) {
        $(items).css({opacity: 0});
    });
    ias.on('rendered', function (items) {
        msnry.appended(items);
    });

    $("dt").click(function () {  
        $(this).toggleClass("close open");
        $(this).next("dd").slideToggle("fast", function () { 
            $('.portfolio').masonry();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

So i have to bring it all together.... Thanks for your advice!

Comment: For the `click` event to work you may use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Apart from applying masonry to loaded images (I infer), is there any other reason why you need imagesloaded functions? Does masonry work ok without it?

Comment: no, masonry doesnt work ok without it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var container = document.querySelector('#selector');
var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.selector'
});

var ias = $.ias({
  container: "#selector",
  item: ".selector-ajax",
  pagination: "#pagination",
  next: ".next a",
  delay: 1200
});

ias.on('render', function(items) {
  $(items).css({ opacity: 0 });
});

ias.on('rendered', function(items) {
  $container = $("#selector");
  $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      var el = $(items);
      el.css('display', 'none');
      $container.append(el);
      $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          el.css('display', 'inline');
          $container.masonry('appended', el, true);
          });
      });
});
```